# How to uninstall antiviral software (Avast) when normal process fails with "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file"?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, avast

In switching antivirus software, I disabled Avast and am now trying to uninstall it through the normal Apps & features control panel of Windows 10. After confirming with Windows 10 that the uninstall program should be allowed to make changes, the uninstall fails with the message:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

Attempting to add permissions or change ownership of the Avast folder and sub-objects through either Windows Explorer or the command line (run as administrator) fails.

I've temporarily disabled the other AV application, but to no affect.

How else can I try to get the uninstallation to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After re-enabling Avast's shields, the uninstall program launched as expected through the Apps & features control panel.